# Using SurfaceTexture in Android

Tags: android, media-player, opengl-es-2.0, xoom

I want to play a video into an OpenGL texture on XOOM using Android 3.0.
I have come across SurfaceTexture in the goole developer docs which has been added in API 11
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture.html

The documentation talks about using GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES instead of GL_TEXTURE_2D, I cannot find any reference to this define in the latest android-ndk-r5c, it's not defined in  in the ndk and it only goes up to platform-9, so I guess I would need platform-11 and there appears to be no android.opengl.GLES20Ext which I guess is where it would reside on the java side.

I have the latest of all released android tools from google and I cannot find any extra things from NVidia or Motorola on their developer sites.

Do anyone have a working example of using SurfaceTexture to either put the camera image or video onto an OpenGL texture? and/or know what I am missing to be able to use this new functionality?

Answer (score 15):

A demo locate https://github.com/crossle/MediaPlayerSurface

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.SurfaceTexture;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.opengl.GLES20;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.opengl.Matrix;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Surface;

class VideoSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {

    VideoRender mRenderer;
    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = null;

    public VideoSurfaceView(Context context, MediaPlayer mp) {
        super(context);

        setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
        mMediaPlayer = mp;
        mRenderer = new VideoRender(context);
        setRenderer(mRenderer);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        queueEvent(new Runnable(){
                public void run() {
                    mRenderer.setMediaPlayer(mMediaPlayer);
                }});

        super.onResume();
    }

    private static class VideoRender
        implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer, SurfaceTexture.OnFrameAvailableListener {
        private static String TAG = "VideoRender";

        private static final int FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES = 4;
        private static final int TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_STRIDE_BYTES = 5 * FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES;
        private static final int TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_POS_OFFSET = 0;
        private static final int TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_UV_OFFSET = 3;
        private final float[] mTriangleVerticesData = {
            // X, Y, Z, U, V
            -1.0f, -1.0f, 0, 0.f, 0.f,
            1.0f, -1.0f, 0, 1.f, 0.f,
            -1.0f,  1.0f, 0, 0.f, 1.f,
            1.0f,  1.0f, 0, 1.f, 1.f,
        };

        private FloatBuffer mTriangleVertices;

        private final String mVertexShader =
                "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;\n" +
                "uniform mat4 uSTMatrix;\n" +
                "attribute vec4 aPosition;\n" +
                "attribute vec4 aTextureCoord;\n" +
                "varying vec2 vTextureCoord;\n" +
                "void main() {\n" +
                "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * aPosition;\n" +
                "  vTextureCoord = (uSTMatrix * aTextureCoord).xy;\n" +
                "}\n";

        private final String mFragmentShader =
                "#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require\n" +
                "precision mediump float;\n" +
                "varying vec2 vTextureCoord;\n" +
                "uniform samplerExternalOES sTexture;\n" +
                "void main() {\n" +
                "  gl_FragColor = texture2D(sTexture, vTextureCoord);\n" +
                "}\n";

        private float[] mMVPMatrix = new float[16];
        private float[] mSTMatrix = new float[16];

        private int mProgram;
        private int mTextureID;
        private int muMVPMatrixHandle;
        private int muSTMatrixHandle;
        private int maPositionHandle;
        private int maTextureHandle;

        private SurfaceTexture mSurface;
        private boolean updateSurface = false;

        private static int GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES = 0x8D65;

        private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;

        public VideoRender(Context context) {
            mTriangleVertices = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
                mTriangleVerticesData.length * FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES)
                    .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
            mTriangleVertices.put(mTriangleVerticesData).position(0);

            Matrix.setIdentityM(mSTMatrix, 0);
        }

        public void setMediaPlayer(MediaPlayer player) {
            mMediaPlayer = player;
        }

        public void onDrawFrame(GL10 glUnused) {
            synchronized(this) {
                if (updateSurface) {
                    mSurface.updateTexImage();
                    mSurface.getTransformMatrix(mSTMatrix);
                    updateSurface = false;
                }
            }

            GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
            GLES20.glClear( GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

            GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);
            checkGlError("glUseProgram");

            GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
            GLES20.glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, mTextureID);

            mTriangleVertices.position(TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_POS_OFFSET);
            GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(maPositionHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_STRIDE_BYTES, mTriangleVertices);
            checkGlError("glVertexAttribPointer maPosition");
            GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maPositionHandle);
            checkGlError("glEnableVertexAttribArray maPositionHandle");

            mTriangleVertices.position(TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_UV_OFFSET);
            GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(maTextureHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_STRIDE_BYTES, mTriangleVertices);
            checkGlError("glVertexAttribPointer maTextureHandle");
            GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maTextureHandle);
            checkGlError("glEnableVertexAttribArray maTextureHandle");

            Matrix.setIdentityM(mMVPMatrix, 0);
            GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(muMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mMVPMatrix, 0);
            GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(muSTMatrixHandle, 1, false, mSTMatrix, 0);

            GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
            checkGlError("glDrawArrays");
            GLES20.glFinish();

        }

        public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 glUnused, int width, int height) {

        }

        public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 glUnused, EGLConfig config) {
            mProgram = createProgram(mVertexShader, mFragmentShader);
            if (mProgram == 0) {
                return;
            }
            maPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "aPosition");
            checkGlError("glGetAttribLocation aPosition");
            if (maPositionHandle == -1) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Could not get attrib location for aPosition");
            }
            maTextureHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "aTextureCoord");
            checkGlError("glGetAttribLocation aTextureCoord");
            if (maTextureHandle == -1) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Could not get attrib location for aTextureCoord");
            }

            muMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix");
            checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation uMVPMatrix");
            if (muMVPMatrixHandle == -1) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Could not get attrib location for uMVPMatrix");
            }

            muSTMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uSTMatrix");
            checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation uSTMatrix");
            if (muSTMatrixHandle == -1) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Could not get attrib location for uSTMatrix");
            }


            int[] textures = new int[1];
            GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);

            mTextureID = textures[0];
            GLES20.glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, mTextureID);
            checkGlError("glBindTexture mTextureID");

            GLES20.glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
                                   GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
            GLES20.glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,
                                   GLES20.GL_LINEAR);

            /*
             * Create the SurfaceTexture that will feed this textureID,
             * and pass it to the MediaPlayer
             */
            mSurface = new SurfaceTexture(mTextureID);
            mSurface.setOnFrameAvailableListener(this);

            Surface surface = new Surface(mSurface);
            mMediaPlayer.setSurface(surface);
            surface.release();

            try {
                mMediaPlayer.prepare();
            } catch (IOException t) {
                Log.e(TAG, "media player prepare failed");
            }

            synchronized(this) {
                updateSurface = false;
            }

            mMediaPlayer.start();
        }

        synchronized public void onFrameAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface) {
            updateSurface = true;
        }

        private int loadShader(int shaderType, String source) {
            int shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(shaderType);
            if (shader != 0) {
                GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, source);
                GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);
                int[] compiled = new int[1];
                GLES20.glGetShaderiv(shader, GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, compiled, 0);
                if (compiled[0] == 0) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Could not compile shader " + shaderType + ":");
                    Log.e(TAG, GLES20.glGetShaderInfoLog(shader));
                    GLES20.glDeleteShader(shader);
                    shader = 0;
                }
            }
            return shader;
        }

        private int createProgram(String vertexSource, String fragmentSource) {
            int vertexShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexSource);
            if (vertexShader == 0) {
                return 0;
            }
            int pixelShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentSource);
            if (pixelShader == 0) {
                return 0;
            }

            int program = GLES20.glCreateProgram();
            if (program != 0) {
                GLES20.glAttachShader(program, vertexShader);
                checkGlError("glAttachShader");
                GLES20.glAttachShader(program, pixelShader);
                checkGlError("glAttachShader");
                GLES20.glLinkProgram(program);
                int[] linkStatus = new int[1];
                GLES20.glGetProgramiv(program, GLES20.GL_LINK_STATUS, linkStatus, 0);
                if (linkStatus[0] != GLES20.GL_TRUE) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Could not link program: ");
                    Log.e(TAG, GLES20.glGetProgramInfoLog(program));
                    GLES20.glDeleteProgram(program);
                    program = 0;
                }
            }
            return program;
        }

        private void checkGlError(String op) {
            int error;
            while ((error = GLES20.glGetError()) != GLES20.GL_NO_ERROR) {
                Log.e(TAG, op + ": glError " + error);
                throw new RuntimeException(op + ": glError " + error);
            }
        }

    }  // End of class VideoRender.

}  // End of class VideoSurfaceView.
```

Comment: Also, it seems you like you should cite references:

  ./tests/tests/media/src/android/media/cts/TextureRender.java

from

  https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts

Answer (score 6):

Example code. This creates a new external texture suitable for use in a SurfaceTexture, then wraps it in said SurfaceTexture and passes it to the camera as a surface to write the preview into.

```
int[] textures = new int[1];
// generate one texture pointer and bind it as an external texture.
GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, textures[0]);
// No mip-mapping with camera source.
GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES,
        GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
                        GL10.GL_LINEAR);        
GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES,
        GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
// Clamp to edge is only option.
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES,
        GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES,
        GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);


int texture_id = textures[0];
SurfaceTexture mTexture = new SurfaceTexture(texture_id);
mTexture.setOnFrameAvailableListener(this);

Camera cam = Camera.open();
cam.setPreviewTexture(mTexture);
```

Note that if you render this object, you'll need to be careful: It's NOT a 2D texture, so it needs special treatment in the shader.

Answer (score 3):

If using API level 11 to 14 you can just define GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES yourself by placing

```
private static final int GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES = 0x8D65;
```

in your code. This seems to work just fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

NVIDIA has a full and working sample in their TEGRA Android Developer pack. The sample is written pure Java and runs in Standard Eclipse+Android SDK - so you just need to install the samples.
The name of the project is surfacetexture (or something like it). It works nice!
Hopes it helps you.

Comment: It's really unfriendly to post unverified information: http://grokbase.com/t/gg/android-developers/12c6txzw6s/nvidia-sample-missing

Comment: Sorry - NVIDIA has removed it from the their current sample package. If you want - download samples "Tegra Android Developer Pack 1.0r5 [NDK] (Windows, OSX, Linux/32, Linux/64)" from [link](https://developer.nvidia.com/tegra-android-development-pack).

Comment: And ... Project is placed in TDK_Samples\Android_NVIDIA_samples_2_public_RC2\apps-sdk11\surface_texture_java and it works (you'll have to fix an error in SurfaceTextureJavaRenderer.startCamera() (surround mCamera.setPreviewTexture(mSurfTex); with a try-catch.). Hope this gives a little more clarity.