# Android combine two videos overlay the other

Tags: android, video, overlay

How can i combine two videos? One of them is main video, the other one is overlay video which is the small size and placed at the corner. And also result should be single merged video file.

Answer (score 0):

the java port of ffmpeg maybe code.google.com/p/jjmpeg

Comment: I used javacv library but i cant find logical way to solve this problem.

Comment: My problem is similar at this question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15497242/display-two-videos-together-then-output-as-a-merged-video-on-a-single-screen)